# Adding gradient transparency to raster layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, geotiff-tiff, transparency-opacity

I'm using QGIS.

I have about 100 GeoTIFF satellite imagery that makes a circular overall shape. I need to add a gradient transparency to the edges of the whole set to better blend with the lower resolution background imagery.

I played with the Layer Transparency, it can remove the black pixels, but no chance in a distance based gradient.

I tried creating a circle shape layer, placed in the center and colored it with gradient black and white with the ramping part placed just near the edges of GeoTIFFs. Then I used Save As > Rendered Image to save the GeoTIFF's in gradient black and white so I can manually use these images as Alpha channel in another software. But the raster layers do not include the shape layer on top, saved just the imagery itself.

[image: lowered the opacity of the circle to better show underlaying GeoTIFF set]

I'm quite new to GIS software so there might be a much simpler solution that I'm missing.

How would you go about creating this?